# postgresql Wildcard search and ranking not working as expected

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, tsvector

I have this tsvector column for full-text search of two columns' name and address.

```
ALTER TABLE public.business_info ADD column search_vector tsvector NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (setweight(to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, COALESCE(name, ''::text)), 'A'::"char") || setweight(to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, COALESCE(address, ''::text)), 'B'::"char")) STORED
```

I am trying the below query to find records with full text wild card search

```
SELECT name,ts_rank_cd(search_vector, to_tsquery('Oklahoma&State:*')) as rank 
from business_info order by rank desc
```

But I am getting the result as below though I am expecting, records with the name "Oklahoma state" show a higher ranking. Any idea how to rank these results to get the results with a higher ranking on the inputs that the user has given?

[image]

Comment: All of those records do have "Oklahoma state"

Comment: How can we ensure that there will be a high score for the records starting with "Oklahoma state"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are interested on higher score in the *starting positions* of the string, simple define an expression for this part.

Here an example for the first two words

```
select 
coalesce((string_to_array(name, ' '))[1],' ')||' ' || coalesce((string_to_array(name, ' '))[2],' ')  as name_pfx,
name
from business_info;

name_pfx,           name
Southwest Oklahoma  Southwest Oklahoma State University at Oklahoma State University-OKC
```

Than define a higher weight for this prefix e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE  business_info 
ADD column search_vector tsvector NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS 
 (setweight(to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, 
       COALESCE((coalesce((string_to_array(name, ' '))[1],' ')||' ' || coalesce((string_to_array(name, ' '))[2],' ')), ''::text)), 'A'::"char") || 
  setweight(to_tsvector('simple'::regconfig, COALESCE(name, ''::text)), 'B'::"char")) stored;
```

Resut is as expected

```
SELECT name_pfx||' '||name name,ts_rank_cd(search_vector, to_tsquery('Oklahoma&State:*')) as rank 
from  business_info order by rank desc

"rank",  "name"                                      
2.1714287   Oklahoma State Oklahoma State University - Oklahoma City
2.0714285   Oklahoma State Oklahoma State University at Western Oklahoma
0.93333334  Southwest Oklahoma Southwest Oklahoma State University at Oklahoma State University-OKC
0.90000004  Southwest Oklahoma Southwest Oklahoma State University at Northwest Oklahoma State University-A
0.90000004  Western Oklahoma Western Oklahoma State College at Western Oklahoma State College
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use strpos to find how soon in the string another string occurs.  But if the substrig doesn't occur at all, you get 0, so you probably need to deal with that specially:

```
ORDER BY nullif(strpos(name,'Oklahoma state'),0);
```

Note that this will fail to rank somethings that your query still finds, like 'state quick red fox jumps over Oklahoma'.  Using FTS for the match but substring queries for the rank is inconsistent, maybe you should use substring for both.